# String does not conform to type AnyObject in NSarray Swift

Tags: ios, swift, nsarray

I am creating a custom object in swift. One of the properties of that object is an array, meant to contain strings:

```
Exersice (name: "Test", type: "Test", muscles: NSArray(objects: "muscle1", "muscle2"), descriptionString: "Test", pace: true, sets: 1, reps: NSMutableArray(15, 12, 12), time: false, duration: 0)
```

This is the part the question is about:

```
muscles: NSArray(objects: "muscle1", "muscle2")
```

I keep on getting an error:

```
String does not conform to type AnyObject
```

I just don't understand why. Looking around on the web shows many cases of this error, but none in this context or helpful in solving this problem.

How do I get rid of this error? Any help would be highly appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is not `NSArray(objects: "muscle1", "muscle2")`, but this:

```
NSMutableArray(15, 12, 12)
```

This should be

```
NSMutableArray(objects: 15, 12, 12)
```

But, as @NateCook said in his answer, you should use Swift `Array`.

Comment: Thank you so much! I never expected this to be the issue.

Comment: Ha, I didn't even see the rest of rest of the line!

Answer (score 2):

`NSArray` can only hold reference types, whereas Swift's `String` is a value type. String instances are normally automatically bridged to `NSString`, but the constructor you're using for the `NSArray` explicitly expects `AnyObject`, so that kind of bridging is defeated. You should be able to use a Swift `Array` instead:

```
Exersice (name: "Test", type: "Test", muscles: ["muscle1", "muscle2"], ...
```

Comment: Hi! Thank you for your comment. I have implemented your solution but nothing changes, I still get the error

Answer (score 0):

If your Exersice class *expects* a String array anyway, then make sure the initializer declares it takes a string array

```
init(name: String, type: String, muscles: [String]) {}
```

Then Nate's answer above is sufficient.